# Error: edac skx ecc is disabled on imc 0 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I have an ubuntu workstation with intel i9 and Nvidia Graphics Card. While running a Gromacs MD simulation my system crashed and when I start it again, instead of showing ubuntu login, the display shows an error: edac skx ecc is disabled on imc 0.

Comment: I'm regularly getting this myself.

Comment: @ThomasKimber do you have more than one graphic card in your system?

Comment: Yes, I do. Reading your answer below, it started happening not long after I setup a multiple screen display which also involved messing with the xconfig file. Will definitely look into this - thankyou!

Comment: I didn't have an older backup copy of my xconfig file, but I did notice that my monitors were plugged into two DisplayPort sockets, one on the top row of the first card, and the second on the second row of the first card, leaving a second DisplayPort socket free on the top row of the first card. I removed the connection into the second row, and plugged it in so both top-row DisplayPort sockets were filled - and hey presto - this error hasn't returned since.

Comment: Yeah, one should be careful about using simulatneously two display ports in a same graphics card for display. Before doing that a backup file of xconfig file should be created to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out this. Actually, I have two GPU's in my system and xconfig file mentioned the wrong GPU ID for display. I have connected display port to the GPU ID 0 whereas the xconfig file selected the GPU ID 1. I restored xconfig file by replacing the xorg.conf from the original Nvidia xconfig backup file.

Go to tty mode and type following commands

1. cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original /etc/X11/xorg.conf
2. reboot